# Customise UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, xcode4

How can I use more than one UITableView in one ViewController? Is it possible to ause more than one TableView in a page?

Actually i am creating a Application Form, there i have to use objects alternative for combo box.

I choose TableView instead for combo box.

Is this a right method?

Comment: it can be used but instead of using different tableview why don't you use different section in your single table view?

Comment: can u explain. i didn't understand what u mean?

Comment: do you know there are sections in table view?

Comment: I just want this UITableView function as spinner or combo box.And when we clic on next button then another UITableView appears and after choosing the necessary it should disappear. As like we choose our country in some forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can have more than one tableview in a UIViewcontroller . You need set tag for each tableview and with respect to you can load data in the tableview .

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {    
  if(tableview.tag == 1)
 {


 } else if (tableview.tag == 2)
 {

 } 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Definitely Goku, you can use multiple `UITableViews` in a single `UIViewController`.
You just need to condition your both `UITableView`' in [**UITableViewDelegete**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).
For example :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if (tableView == yourFirstTableView) {
            // <do whatever on first table view>...
        } else if (tableView == yourSecondTableView) {
            // <do whatever on second table view>...
        }
    }
```

Just make sure you set the both delegates for both tables :

```
yourFirstTableView.delegate  = self;
yourSecondTableView.delegate = self;
```

See [**this**](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples/tree/master/TwoTableViews/) example in case of doubt.

Comment: actually is it possible to change the colour of UIPickerView.I just want this UITableView function as spinner or combo box or picker.And when we clic on next button then another UITableView appears and after choosing the necessary it should disappear. As like we choose our country in some forms.

Comment: can we animate the appearance of UITableView?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use more than one `UITableView's` in a single `ViewController`. And you can create an application form with it using different sections and using various accessory types .

Comment: Is there any sample projects are available. so that i could refer it before i starts my work?

Comment: Yep giving u the sample codes ... btw check on http://cocoacontrols.com/ ... ull definitely find one there...

Comment: but i couldn't find out what i nedded

Comment: is that possible to change the way of appearing the table into the view

Answer (score 0):

You can use more than one table view in one controller, just define a different delegate for each UITableView instance. You can define new classes specifically to act as table view delegates, and have your controller create instances of these and set each UITableView's delegate property accordingly.

Comment: can we animate the appearance of TableView?

Answer (score 0):

Yes For Sure you can use more than one tableview in single view controller.
Simply Create tableview in xib or manually.

And in methods of Tableview you can write like this

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if(tableview==table1){

    }else if (tableview ==table2){

    }
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(tableview==table1){

    }else if (tableview ==table2){

    } 
}
```